# Avoid duplicates in INSERT INTO SELECT query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have the following two tables:

```
Table1
----------
ID   Name
1    A
2    B
3    C

Table2
----------
ID   Name
1    Z
```

I need to insert data from `Table1` to `Table2`. I can use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Id, Name) SELECT Id, Name FROM Table1
```

However, in my case, duplicate IDs might exist in `Table2` (in my case, it's just "`1`") and I don't want to copy that again as that would throw an error.

I can write something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Id=1)
INSERT INTO Table2 (Id, name) SELECT Id, name FROM Table1 
ELSE
INSERT INTO Table2 (Id, name) SELECT Id, name FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Id<>1
```

Is there a better way to do this without using `IF - ELSE`? I want to avoid two `INSERT INTO-SELECT` statements based on some condition.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id
                    FROM TABLE_2 t2
                   WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Using `NOT IN`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id
                       FROM TABLE_2)
```

Using `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
   SELECT t1.id,
          t1.name
     FROM TABLE_1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
    WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Of the three options, the `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` is less efficient.  See [this link for more details](https://web.archive.org/web/20160518211340/https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

Comment: Just a clarification on the NOT EXISTS version, you'll need a WITH(HOLDLOCK) hint or no locks will be taken (because there are no rows to lock!) so another thread could insert the row under you.

Comment: Interesting, because I have always believed joining to be faster than sub-selects. Perhaps that is for straight joins only, and not applicable to left joins.

Comment: Duncan, joining is often faster that subselects when they are correlated subqueries. If you have the subquery up in the select list a join will often be faster.

Comment: Thanks! option 2 seems like it would be really inefficient. Unless the database is smart enough to know not to fetch the entire results of the subquery?

Comment: @Kip: If you read the link I provided that compares the three options, you'd know that your perception is not correct on SQL Server.  Could be different on other databases, but the columns compared being nullable or not makes a difference too.

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is especially useful with composite primary key, `NOT IN` won't work then

Comment: Any ideas why I would I still get `cannot insert duplicate key...` using any of the above methods?

Comment: @druciferre Possibly a duplicate within the source being inserted.

Comment: `NOT IN` also works in `MYSQL Server`

Answer (score 50):

In MySQL you can do this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2(Id, Name) SELECT Id, Name FROM Table1
```

Does SQL Server have anything similar?

Comment: +1 for educating me on this . Very nice syntax. Definitely shorter and better than the one I used. Unfortunately Sql server does not have this.

Comment: Not totally true. When you create a unique index, you can set it to "ignore duplicates", in which case SQL Server will ignore any attempts to add a duplicate.

Comment: And SQL Server still can't... pathetic.

Comment: So SQL Server still cant?

Comment: And still can't

Comment: And still can't

Comment: And still can't

Answer (score 6):

I just had a similar problem, the DISTINCT keyword works magic:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Id, Name) SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name FROM Table1
```

Comment: Unless I totally misunderstand you, this will work if you have duplicates in the set you're inserting _from_. It won't, however, help if the set you're inserting from might be duplicates of data already in the `insert into` table.

Answer (score 5):

Using `ignore Duplicates` on the unique index [as suggested by IanC here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513174/sql-server-insert-into-select-to-avoid-duplicates/27948050#comment4816524_2513478) was my solution for a similar issue, creating the index with the Option `WITH  IGNORE_DUP_KEY`

```
In backward compatible syntax
, WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY is equivalent to WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON.
```

Ref.: [index_option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms186869.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem recently...
Heres what worked for me in MS SQL server 2017...
The primary key should be set on ID in table 2...
The columns and column properties should be the same of course between both tables. This will work the first time you run the below script. The duplicate ID in table 1, will not insert...

If you run it the second time, you will get a

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint error

This is the code:

```
Insert into Table_2
Select distinct *
from Table_1
where table_1.ID >1
```

Answer (score 4):

From SQL Server you can set a *Unique key* index on the table for (Columns that needs to be unique)

[image: From sql server right click on the table design select Indexes/Keys]

[image: Select column(s) that will be not duplicate , then type Unique Key]

Comment: It doesn't response to alternate of INSERT INGORE INTO.

Answer (score 2):

A little off topic, but if you want to migrate the data to a new table, and the possible duplicates are in the *original table*, and the column possibly duplicated is not an id, a `GROUP BY` will do:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
(name)
  SELECT t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
  GROUP BY t1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had duplicate IDs in the source table, so none of the proposals worked. I don't care about performance, it's just done once.
To solve this I took the records one by one with a cursor to ignore the duplicates.

So here's the code example:

```
DECLARE @c1 AS VARCHAR(12);
DECLARE @c2 AS VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @c3 AS VARCHAR(250);


DECLARE MY_cursor CURSOR STATIC FOR
Select
c1,
c2,
c3
from T2
where ....;

OPEN MY_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_cursor INTO @c1, @c2, @c3

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    if (select count(1) 
        from T1
        where a1 = @c1
        and a2 = @c2
        ) = 0 
            INSERT INTO T1
            values (@c1, @c2, @c3)

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_cursor INTO @c1, @c2, @c3
END
CLOSE MY_cursor
DEALLOCATE MY_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a MERGE query to fill a table without duplications.
The problem I had was a double key in the tables ( Code , Value ) ,
and the exists query was very slow
The MERGE executed very fast ( more then X100 )

[examples for MERGE query](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-merge-statement-overview-and-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

For one table it works perfectly when creating one unique index from multiple field. Then simple "INSERT IGNORE" will ignore duplicates if ALL of 7 fields (in this case) will have SAME values.

Select fields in PMA Structure View and click Unique, new combined index will be created.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

A simple `DELETE` before the `INSERT` would suffice:

```
DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE Id = (SELECT Id FROM Table1)
INSERT INTO Table2 (Id, name) SELECT Id, name FROM Table1
```

Switching `Table1` for `Table2` depending on which table's `Id` and `name` pairing you want to preserve.

Comment: Please don't do this.  You're basically saying "whatever data I had is worthless, let's just insert this new data!"

Comment: @Andir If for some reason "Table2" shouldn't getting dropped after the "INSERT" then use the other methods, but this is a perfectly valid way to achieve what the OP asked.

Comment: Valid, but certainly slower and potentially corrupting without a transaction.  If you go this route, wrap in a TRANSaction.

Comment: Despite all the whining about this answer, it may be the best solution depending on the situation.