# Do conditional INSERT with SQL?

Tags: sql, database, smallsql

I have a database that is updated with datasets from time to time. Here it may happen that a dataset is delivered that already exists in database.

Currently I'm first doing a

```
SELECT FROM ... WHERE val1=... AND val2=...
```

to check, if a dataset with these data already exists (using the data in WHERE-statement). If this does not return any value, I'm doing my INSERT.

But this seems to be a bit complicated for me. So my question: is there some kind of conditional INSERT that adds a new dataset only in case it does not exist?

I'm using **[SmallSQL](http://www.smallsql.de/)**

Comment: ***WHAT*** database system is this for? SQL is just the query language - used by many database products. SQL is **not** a database product in itself. So please let us know if you're using MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, IBM DB2, SQL Server, Firebird - or whatever else it might be...

Comment: Are you talking about [Merge/Upsert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL))?

Comment: You can also just use INSERT IGNORE INTO

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do that with a single statement and a subquery in nearly all relational databases.

```
INSERT INTO targetTable(field1) 
SELECT field1
FROM myTable
WHERE NOT(field1 IN (SELECT field1 FROM targetTable))
```

Certain relational databases have improved syntax for the above, since what you describe is a fairly common task.  SQL Server has a `MERGE` syntax with all kinds of options, and MySQL has optional `INSERT OR IGNORE` syntax.

**Edit:** [SmallSQL's documentation](http://www.smallsql.de/doc/sqlsyntax.html) is fairly sparse as to which parts of the SQL standard it implements.  It may not implement subqueries, and as such you may be unable to follow the advice above, or anywhere else, if you need to stick with SmallSQL.

Comment: If you are using an `INSERT... VALUES ('a,' 'b,' 'c')`, just change your statement to `INSERT... SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c' WHERE...` with no parentheses.

Comment: Note that this approach in PostgresSQL is not gauranteed to always work if there are inserts happening concurrently.

Answer (score 25):

I dont know about SmallSQL, but this works for MSSQL:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue')
    UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

Based on the where-condition, this updates the row if it exists, else it will insert a new one.

I hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I don't think `IF` is part of standard SQL

Comment: This is the first time I am glad that my current employer uses MSSQL databases.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with **`EXISTS`** condition. `WHERE EXISTS` tests for the existence of any records in a subquery. `EXISTS` returns true if the subquery returns one or more records.
Here is an example

```
UPDATE  TABLE_NAME 
SET val1=arg1 , val2=arg2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE val1=arg1 AND val2=arg2)
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be something between "SELECT" AND "FROM" (other than a space)?

Comment: @LonnieBest - Probably a `select val1, val2 from table_name ...` is what was meant.

Answer (score 1):

I write this solution based on MERGE statement in SQL Server. Please note that the "source" in MERGE mustn't always be a table.

```
MERGE [my_target_table] t
USING (SELECT [val1]=... , [val2]=...) s
ON t.[val1]=s.[val1] AND t.[val2]=s.[val2]
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE set t.[val1]=s.[val1] ,
                    t.[val2]=s.[val2]
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT  ([val1], [val2])
    VALUES (s.[val1] , s.[val2]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you make the thing you don't want duplicates of unique, and allow the database itself to refuse the insert.

Otherwise, you can use INSERT INTO, see [How to avoid duplicates in INSERT INTO SELECT query in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513174/sql-server-insert-into-select-to-avoid-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do an "upsert" one of the most efficient ways currently in SQL Server for single rows is this:

```
UPDATE myTable ...


IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO myTable ....
```

You can also use the `MERGE` syntax if you're doing this with sets of data rather than single rows.

If you want to `INSERT` and not `UPDATE` then you can just write your single `INSERT` statement and use `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Late addition: This worked nicely on PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2)
SELECT value1, value2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE column1=value1 AND column2=value2)
```

To be noted: This is actually an extension to the question allowing to add entries in multiple columns as long as the combination is not yet existing; actually any arbitrary condition could be applied.