# MSSQL Namespace Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

On a SQL Server I have a table namespace

```
Namespace
---------
Prefix
com.foo
com.bar
com.foobar
```

And I want to prevent inserts if a conflicting namespace already exists. A namespace includes all sub namespace. E.g. com.foo includes everything 'below' com.foo e.g. com.foo.bar and com.foo.bar.baz but not com.foobar or com.foobar.baz (com.foobar is a different namespace than com.foo)

The check should be atomic to prevent concurrency issues.

I have this insert that does the insert conditionally. But I am not sure if it is atomic.

```
INSERT INTO namespace
(PREFIX)
SELECT t1.PREFIX
FROM namespace t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT t2.PREFIX
                 FROM namespace t2
                 WHERE t2.PREFIX in ('com.foo.bar','com.foo','com'))
```

The comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16636779/1844551 suggests that with Postgres it is not guaranteed to be atomic. How about MSSQL?

Ideally this would be a check constraint, but I don't know how to construct the `where t2.PREFIX in ('com.foo.bar','com.foo','com')` from an input like `com.foo.bar`.

Note: a simple startswith doesn't do the trick since `com.foo` and `com.foobar` are different namespaces that don't conflict each other. So `com.foobar` can be inserted if `com.foo` exists.

So my current idea is to implement this query in the client code and check the result if something was inserted.

Is there a better way to implement this in the DB as a constraint?

Comment: What about a unique constraint?

Comment: Not enough. com.foo.bar should not be inserted if com.foo exists.

Comment: It seems like you're working with data that describes a hierarchy. It would probably be better to *model the hierarchy* within the database rather than having to (re-)construct it from a string.

Comment: Looks like you need a self-referencing foreign key. But for your query above: `HOLDLOCK` hint or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level will guarantee atomicity

Comment: I'm lost.  Your sample query is referring to the same table twice, so if the `where` clause passes, it is going to insert duplicates.  That seems highly suspicious.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right, the query is not doing what I expected. It's just a sample for a conditional insert that I took form stackoverflow and tried to adapt to my case.

Comment: @Charlieface I can imagine modeling the hierarchy but how would that help with the constraint? I would still need a lock and some procedure to check for conflicts, right?

Comment: You can just check for inserting the same key with the same parent

Comment: @Charlieface That is the same problem as with a simple unique constraint. The existing entry and the one that I want to insert are not necessarily the same. If com.foo exists it has a different parent than com.foo.bar that I want to insert. Yet com.foo.bar must not be inserted.

Comment: You could model it so that you always insert the upper levels also, with a `DoesInherit bit` flag saying whether it includes child namespaces. Then when you insert a child namespace, you generate all the necessary nodes, and check against any existing parent nodes with `DoesInherit = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to check for conflicts with this `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO namespace (PREFIX)
    SELECT v.PREFIX
    FROM (VALUES ('com.foo.bar')) v(prefix);
```

You can use:

```
INSERT INTO namespace (PREFIX)
    SELECT v.PREFIX
    FROM (VALUES ('com.foo.bar')) v(prefix)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM namespace n
                      WHERE v.prefix LIKE n.prefix + '.%'
                     );
```

I cannot think of a simple way to implement this logic as a constraint.  That leaves basically three options:

- Use manual coding as above, perhaps embedded in a stored procedure.
- Use a trigger.
- Use a user-defined function with a `check` constraint.