# sql approach to allow web application user to insert based on permissions

Tags: sql

I'm building a small web application which contains user types of User or Admin.
Within my users table, I have a boolean flag, `is_admin`. I'm trying to design a query such that a web application user can perform an insert into a table if `is_admin` is true.

Is there a clear way to write an insert query where a boolean value is true? Should I be using a procedure or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do conditional INSERT with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636698/do-conditional-insert-with-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check first if it is `is_admin` from users table and then insert into another table.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE is_admin=1 ) 
    INSERT INTO Table
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks for your reply