# SQL insert query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with this piece of SQL and I was wondering if someone could help me out.

```
INSERT INTO table_1(
rec_1, 
rec_2, 
rec_3
) 
VALUES (
val_1, 
val_2, 
val_3
)
```

Now, rec_2 and rec_3 are clear and have absolute values.
Rec_1 is filled with values from another table. Now I want to insert the values from the other table which do not exist already in this table. I was guessing I should use WHERE NOT IN?

So it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(
rec_1, 
rec_2, 
rec_3
) 
VALUES (
val_1,
val_2, 
val_3
) 
WHERE NOT IN (
SELECT rec FROM table_2
)
```

But.. How can I insert those values in rec_1 in my query?

Comment: 'NOT IN' instead of not exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a simple `INSERT/SELECT` if `rec_2` and `rec_3` are absolute values:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (rec_1, rec_2, rec_3)
SELECT val_1, 'val_2', 'val_3'
FROM other_table
WHERE val_1 NOT IN (SELECT rec_1 FROM table_1)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO table_1(rec_1, rec_2, rec_3) 
SELECT val_1, val_2, val_3 FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT rec FROM table_2)
```

You might want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513187/2450409) for further usage

Further details [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO table_1(rec_1, rec_2, rec_3) 
SELECT  val_1, val_2, val_3 FROM tablename 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT rec FROM table_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     4 ways to insert record
 1--> {Simple Insertion when table column sequence is known}
        Insert into Table1
        values(1,2,...)

    2--> {Simple insertion mention column}  
        Insert into Table1(col2,col4)
        values(1,2)

    3--> {bulk insertion when num of selected collumns of a table(#table2) are equal to Insertion table(Table1) }   
        Insert into Table1 {Column sequence}
        Select * -- column sequence should be same.
           from #table2

    4--> {bulk insertion when you want to insert only into desired column of a table(table1)}
        Insert into Table1 (Column1,Column2 ....Desired Column from Table1)  
        Select Column1,Column2..desired column from #table2
           from #table2
```