# TSQL : Check inserting data into the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

Let's say I have this table  :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[finaleTable](
    [VENDId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [companyName] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    ----Others field

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   ([VENDId])
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And this query :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.finaleTable
SELECT *
FROM Tmp1
```

Before inserting data into the table i have to check the integrity constraint on these 2 fields. If the values exist then move to the next line of data taken from table TMP1. if they do not exist then insert the line.

Could you suggest how can i progress to do this?

Comment: `where Tmp1.VENDId not in (select VENDId from dbo.finaleTable)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid duplicates in INSERT INTO SELECT query in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513174/how-to-avoid-duplicates-in-insert-into-select-query-in-sql-server)

Comment: @AlexK. I think your solution can do that, i 'll test

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! this one seems like it would be really inefficient if i have more than one field as primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `MERGE` like this:

```
MERGE dbo.finaleTable AS target
USING (SELECT VENDId, companyName... FROM Tmp1) AS source
ON target.VENDId = source.VENDId AND ISNULL(target.companyName,'') = ISNULL(source.companyName,'')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (VENDId, companyName...)
    VALUES (source.VENDId, source.companyName...)
```

If `companyName` needed to be checked it must be `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use where exists -

```
insert into finaleTable
select * from table1 as a
where not exists(select 1 from finaleTable as b where b.VENDId = a.VENDId)
```