# Remove inserting new records which are already available in destination table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I I have 2 server 2009 and 2012 server. I have inserted data from 2012 server data to a new staging table, now i have to insert 2009 server data into same staging table. If 2009 data record matches with existing record then i dont want to insert that record and rest all other data should insert into staging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid duplicates in INSERT INTO SELECT query in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513174/how-to-avoid-duplicates-in-insert-into-select-query-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a linked server for server 2008. Write an `OPENQUERY` to access the server 2008 table.

Now Use the Execute SQL task of SSIS and use SQL Server 2008 table except server 2012 table.

Comment: Thanks User2799436, Mr. Bhosale and Sérgio. I have created a linked server and used the EST task and used the above query which you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try below Query

Using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id
                    FROM TABLE_2 t2
                   WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Using `NOT IN`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id
                       FROM TABLE_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative to the answer given using joins instead of exits:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id = null
```

This can be easier to read when multiple staging tables or "complementary" tables (add data from other tables joined).

Regards,
Sérgio