# What is the correct way to use SQL Where Not Exist and data type casting?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have table A and B, table A contains 30 rows of ID and table B contains 60 rows of ID, I want to insert B.ID into A.ID by using where not exist. Table B ID will be inserted into Table A if the B.ID does not exist in Table A.

```
INSERT INTO A(
ID)
SELECT ID
FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select ID From A WHERE A.ID =  B.ID)
```

I think there are some problems in my subqueries. Please advice me on how to correct this.

Suppose A.ID is in NVARCHAR(200) type and B.ID is in FLOAT type.

```
INSERT INTO A(
ID)
SELECT Cast(Cast(ID as Float)as Nvarchar)
FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select ID From A WHERE A.ID =  B.ID)
```

But there is still error: Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

TIA!

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid duplicates in INSERT INTO SELECT query in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513174/how-to-avoid-duplicates-in-insert-into-select-query-in-sql-server)

Comment: ok this problem is solved, thanks Mark, but here comes another error: Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use join instead of sub query for better performance

```
INSERT INTO A(ID)
SELECT CAST(B.ID AS nvarchar(200))
FROM A RIGHT JOIN B ON A.ID = CAST(B.ID AS NVARCHAR(200)) WHERE A.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO A(
ID)
SELECT CAST(B.ID AS nvarchar(200))
FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.ID =  CAST(B.ID AS nvarchar(200)))
```

But I would like you to take a look at [Unique Constraints and Check Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).