# Insert into table from another table where the records don't exist

Tags: sql, insert, teradata, sql-insert, insert-into

I'm trying to figure out how to insert into an existing table (tbl01) from a temporary table (temp) where the records do not already exist in the existing table (tbl01).  I hope that makes sense.  I'm basically, trying to update a table with records that have occurred since the last update of the table.  Here's my code so far:

```
insert into tbl01
(sale_store, sale_dt, sale_register, sale_trans)
select distinct
sale_store, sale_dt, sale_register, sale_trans
from temp
where NOT EXISTS (select * from tbl01)
```

***The issue that I'm having is that it runs, but does not put any new records into the table*** - there should be be lots of new records.  I'm sure it's something small and stupid I'm missing.  I used this post as my guide: [How to avoid duplicates in INSERT INTO SELECT query in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513174/how-to-avoid-duplicates-in-insert-into-select-query-in-sql-server)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you determine a distinct record in your `tbl01`. Is it `sales_store`, or multiple fields? `NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)` runs the select statement and if it has ANY records then `NOT EXISTS` fails, so you either need a correlated subquery, or to use a '<field> NOT IN (SELECT <field> FROM...)`

Comment: Those four fields together create a 'distinct' record.  So I need to include all four of those fields as something like:

    where not exists (select sale_store, sale_dt, sale_register, sale_trans 
    from tbl01

Comment: If your target is created as a SET table and your PK includes all columns you can simply INSERT/SELECT with no WHERE, duplicates rows are silently discarded by a SET table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your inner query does not depend on the temp table in any way. Basically, what you wrote was "insert into `tbl01` if no records exists in `tbl01`". To fix it you need to add a where clause to the query inside the `exists`:

```
insert into tbl01
(sale_store, sale_dt, sale_register, sale_trans)
select distinct
sale_store, sale_dt, sale_register, sale_trans
from temp
where NOT EXISTS (
    select * 
    from tbl01
    where temp.sale_store = tbl01.sale_store 
    and temp.sale_dt = tbl01.sale_dt
    and temp.sale_register = tbl01.sale_register
    and temp.sale_trans = tbl01.sale_trans)
```

Comment: Based on the comments in the question the primary key is all 4 fields.

Comment: Thank you, Zohar!  This made sense on making sure the key didn't exist. Perfect!