# Insert or update rows in MS Access database in Python

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I've got an MS Access table (SearchAdsAccountLevel) which needs to be updated frequently from a python script. I've set up the pyodbc connection and now I would like to UPDATE/INSERT rows from my pandas df to the MS Access table based on whether the Date_ AND CampaignId fields match with the df data.

Looking at previous examples I've built the UPDATE statement which uses iterrows to iterate through all rows within df and execute the SQL code as per below:

```
    connection_string = (
            r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
            r"c:\AccessDatabases\Database2.accdb;"
    )
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
    crsr = cnxn.cursor()

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
            crsr.execute("UPDATE SearchAdsAccountLevel SET [OrgId]=?, [CampaignName]=?, [CampaignStatus]=?, [Storefront]=?, [AppName]=?, [AppId]=?, [TotalBudgetAmount]=?, [TotalBudgetCurrency]=?, [DailyBudgetAmount]=?, [DailyBudgetCurrency]=?, [Impressions]=?, [Taps]=?, [Conversions]=?, [ConversionsNewDownloads]=?, [ConversionsRedownloads]=?, [Ttr]=?, [LocalSpendAmount]=?, [LocalSpendCurrency]=?, [ConversionRate]=?, [Week_]=?, [Month_]=?, [Year_]=?, [Quarter]=?, [FinancialYear]=?, [RowUpdatedTime]=? WHERE [Date_]=? AND [CampaignId]=?",
                        row['OrgId'],
                        row['CampaignName'],
                        row['CampaignStatus'],
                        row['Storefront'],
                        row['AppName'],
                        row['AppId'],
                        row['TotalBudgetAmount'],
                        row['TotalBudgetCurrency'],
                        row['DailyBudgetAmount'],
                        row['DailyBudgetCurrency'],
                        row['Impressions'],
                        row['Taps'],
                        row['Conversions'],
                        row['ConversionsNewDownloads'],
                        row['ConversionsRedownloads'],
                        row['Ttr'],
                        row['LocalSpendAmount'],
                        row['LocalSpendCurrency'],
                        row['ConversionRate'],
                        row['Week_'],
                        row['Month_'],
                        row['Year_'],
                        row['Quarter'],
                        row['FinancialYear'],
                        row['RowUpdatedTime'],
                        row['Date_'],
                        row['CampaignId'])
crsr.commit()
```

I would like to iterate through each row within my df (around 3000) and if the ['Date_'] AND ['CampaignId'] match I UPDATE all other fields. Otherwise I want to INSERT the whole df row in my Access Table (create new row). What's the most efficient and effective way to achieve this?

Comment: There is a lot of ways and steps to affront your quetion. 1- Dont execute queries one by one, use parametrizable query. 2- Use yield's in python ...

Comment: @Ilmari - Done. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider  [`DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and pass list into an  `executemany` call, making sure to order columns accordingly for the `UPDATE` query:

```
cols = ['OrgId', 'CampaignName', 'CampaignStatus', 'Storefront',
        'AppName', 'AppId', 'TotalBudgetAmount', 'TotalBudgetCurrency',
        'DailyBudgetAmount', 'DailyBudgetCurrency', 'Impressions',
        'Taps', 'Conversions', 'ConversionsNewDownloads', 'ConversionsRedownloads',
        'Ttr', 'LocalSpendAmount', 'LocalSpendCurrency', 'ConversionRate',
        'Week_', 'Month_', 'Year_', 'Quarter', 'FinancialYear',
        'RowUpdatedTime', 'Date_', 'CampaignId']

sql = '''UPDATE SearchAdsAccountLevel 
            SET [OrgId]=?, [CampaignName]=?, [CampaignStatus]=?, [Storefront]=?, 
                [AppName]=?, [AppId]=?, [TotalBudgetAmount]=?, 
                [TotalBudgetCurrency]=?, [DailyBudgetAmount]=?, 
                [DailyBudgetCurrency]=?, [Impressions]=?, [Taps]=?, [Conversions]=?, 
                [ConversionsNewDownloads]=?, [ConversionsRedownloads]=?, [Ttr]=?, 
                [LocalSpendAmount]=?, [LocalSpendCurrency]=?, [ConversionRate]=?,
                [Week_]=?, [Month_]=?, [Year_]=?, [Quarter]=?, [FinancialYear]=?, 
                [RowUpdatedTime]=? 
          WHERE [Date_]=? AND [CampaignId]=?'''

crsr.executemany(sql, df[cols].values.tolist())   
cnxn.commit()
```

For the insert, use a temp, staging table with exact structure as final table which you can create with make-table query: `SELECT TOP 1 * INTO temp FROM final`. This temp table will be regularly cleaned out and inserted with all data frame rows. The final query migrates only new rows from temp into final with [`NOT EXISTS`, `NOT IN`, or `LEFT JOIN/NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513187/1422451). You can run this query anytime and never worry about duplicates per *Date_* and *CampaignId* columns.

```
# CLEAN OUT TEMP
sql = '''DELETE FROM SearchAdsAccountLevel_Temp'''
crsr.executemany(sql)   
cnxn.commit()

# APPEND TO TEMP
sql = '''INSERT INTO SearchAdsAccountLevel_Temp (OrgId, CampaignName, CampaignStatus, Storefront,
                                AppName, AppId, TotalBudgetAmount, TotalBudgetCurrency,
                                DailyBudgetAmount, DailyBudgetCurrency, Impressions,
                                Taps, Conversions, ConversionsNewDownloads, ConversionsRedownloads,
                                Ttr, LocalSpendAmount, LocalSpendCurrency, ConversionRate,
                                Week_, Month_, Year_, Quarter, FinancialYear,
                                RowUpdatedTime, Date_, CampaignId)    
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                 ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                 ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);'''

crsr.executemany(sql, df[cols].values.tolist())   
cnxn.commit()

# MIGRATE TO FINAL
sql = '''INSERT INTO SearchAdsAccountLevel 
         SELECT t.* 
         FROM SearchAdsAccountLevel_Temp t
         LEFT JOIN SearchAdsAccountLevel f
            ON t.Date_ = f.Date_ AND t.CampaignId = f.CampaignId
         WHERE f.OrgId IS NULL'''
crsr.executemany(sql)   
cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: how can I also integrate an insert query to create rows which are not currently present in my table but are in df?

Comment: That is a different question than this as it involves a different query and data handling. Usually, staging temp tables are used to avoid append duplicates with [`NOT IN, NOT EXISTS, LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513187/1422451) clauses against final tables in an `INSERT...SELECT` call.

Comment: +1 for the `df[cols].values` hint. To be fair, the "insert" aspect was part of the question (although buried near the bottom), and that is covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919138/2144390) via a comment to [the dup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55901296/2144390).

Comment: @Mtra, see edit with `INSERT` query section which as mentioned requires use of a temp table.

Comment: Instead of creating a temp table, can I run an Insert statement with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on the Date_ and CampaignId fields?

Comment: MS Access does not support such an `INSERT` statement though other DBMS' may. Also, you only need to create temp table once.

Comment: When trying the #Append to Temp step I'm getting the following error: DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (-3030) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: One or more of your data frame column types do not match database table types. Try importing a `select` query of few rows with `read_sql` and compare dtypes with your current df.

Comment: Yeah you were right. I had some 'None' values which weren't being recognized. I've managed to update my final table and insert data into the temp table. Now when trying to migrate temp table to final table I'm getting the following: IntegrityError: ('23000' [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.)

Comment: I thought this was happening due to having duplicates in the index column ('ID') which auto increments in MS Access. I tried to workaround this by omitting this column in the INSERT and SELECT statements but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to explicitly name the columns in last append query's `INSERT` and `SELECT` clauses. For latter, do not use the abbreviated `*`.