# Avoid duplicates on INSERT INTO SELECT query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I avoid duplicate using the provided below query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Entities(EntityId, [Name], [Description], [Type], Source)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CUST_CODE, NAME, FULLDESCRIPTION, 'Agency' AS Type, 'SunDbAgencies' AS Source
    FROM dbo.VW_SUNDB_AGENCIES
```

I've already tried all the answers here :

[Avoid duplicates in INSERT INTO SELECT query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513174/avoid-duplicates-in-insert-into-select-query-in-sql-server) to no avail.

The duplicates are in the `dbo.VW_SUNDB_AGENCIES TABLES` not the `INSERT` table, So I gather I need a way to remove duplicate from the select before inserting

Here is one of the duplicates which is why a simple distinct doesn't work:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `select distinct` is not sufficient.  You still have duplicates in the underlying table, but with different names or descriptions.

I view this as a problem.  But, you can work around it by selecting one arbitrary row per `cust_code`, using `row_number()`:

```
insert into dbo.Entities (EntityId, [Name], [Description], [Type], Source)
  select CUST_CODE, NAME, FULLDESCRIPTION, 'Agency' AS [Type], 'SunDbAgencies' AS Source
  from (select a.*,
               row_number() over (partitoin by cust_code order by cust_code) as seqnum
        from dbo.VW_SUNDB_AGENCIES a
       ) a
  where seqnum = 1 and
        not exists (select 1 from dbo.Entities E where A.CUST_CODE = E.EntityId);
```

Comment: The view is definitely a problem , but I can't change it. The provided script works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I just faced the same problem a couple days ago.  I love the 'Where rownumber = 1' solution.  Very, very, very elegant.