# how to move sql table entry to different table

Tags: php

there is my code sample that deletes data from queue_db,I need code which inserts queue_db values to staff_db table.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCPBL.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem, needs to be posted in text form, and properly formatted. Do not post _images of_ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL query

**Copy all record one table to another**

---

```
 insert into staff_db select * from queue_db
```

This will transfer the data one table to another, later you can delete records conditionally from first table

If the columns names are different then

**Copy all record one table to another with column name alias**

---

```
 insert into staff_tb(column1, column2, column3) select c as column1, b as column2, d as column3 from queue_db
```

where c,b,d are the columns in the second table

If you want to filter it with condition then add `where` at the end of the query with `<tablename.columnname> = <value>`

**Copy all record one table to another without duplicates**

---

To prevent duplicates, you can use this answer [Prevent Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513174/avoid-duplicates-in-insert-into-select-query-in-sql-server) I don't want repeat the same answer here

If you want copy those data into fresh new table like doing a backup then

**Copy all record one table to a fresh new table**

---

```
 select * into newtable from queue_db
```

Then you run delete query for table which you copied from

**Delete all records from a table**

---

```
 delete from queue_db
```

Comment: What about duplicates? from `queue_db` during each inserting

Comment: I have given the answer

Comment: thank you <3 I have 1 more problem now,how can I insert this entry to new table and also delete from previous table?

Comment: you need to run two query the `into` query and `delete` query one after one, updated the answer