# How to insert new rows only on tables without Primary or Foreign Keys?

Tags: t-sql

Scenario: I have two tables. Table A and Table B, both have the same exact columns. My task is to create a master table. I need to ensure no duplicates are in the master table unless it is a new record.

problem: Whoever built the tables did not assign a Primary Key to the table.

Attempts: I attempted running an INSERT INTO WHERE NOT EXISTS query (below as an example not the actual query I ran)

Question: the portion of the query below  `WHERE t2.id = t1.id` confuses me, my table has a multitude of columns, there is no id column like I said it has no PRIMARY key to anchor the match, so, in a scenario where all I have are values without primary keys, how can I append only new records? Also, perhaps I am going about this the wrong way but are there any other functions or options through TSQL worth considering? Maybe not an INSERT INTO statement or perhaps something else? My SQL skills aren't yet that advance so I am not asking for a solution but perhaps ideas or other methods worth considering? Any ideas are welcome.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (id, name)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id
                    FROM TABLE_2 t2
                   WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Comment: You can have a column called `id` and not have a primary key.  Most likely the column *should* be the PK, but it doesn't *have* to be. (I am assuming you're saying that the above query is working, but you don't know why?)

Comment: You say you have a multitude of columns, what constitutes a duplicate?  You will have to WHERE on all of those fields.

Comment: I found that query online as a way to help me with this issue I have, I used it in my question as a way to show that I attempted to resolve this issue using that method, but my problem or question lies in the = portion near the bottom. In it it makes an equality on the id, but like I said, these tables were built without a Primary Key or ID.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513174/avoid-duplicates-in-insert-into-select-query-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would need to amend the SQL sample you posted by changing the condition t2.id = t1.id to whatever columns you do have.

Say your 2 tables have name and brand columns and you don't want duplicates, just change the sample to:

WHERE t2.name = t1.name
AND t2.brand = t1.brand

This will ensure you don't insert and rows in table 2 from table 1 which are duplicates. You would have to make sure the where condition contains all columns (you said the table schemas are identical).

Also, the above code sample copies everything into table 2 - but you said you want a master table - so you'd have to change it to insert into the master table, not table 2.

Comment: I am trying this now, I will get back to you, this I understand I think.